# sound waves , standing waves,wind chimes

Tags: acoustics, frequency, wavelength, textbook-erratum, normal-modes

[image]I don't know how to approach this problem. It's been bothering me for months. The answer seems to be the rod with shortest length

[image]

Comment: Please help me with how to approach this problem?

Comment: @Pieter the answer to this is c but as we know that frequency is inversely proportional to length

Comment: @Pieter I want to know how you came to this conclusion

Comment: Now already three people want to close this as a homework question. That is clearly not the case. It is something that has been nagging the poster for months. And I believe that there is no better place to ask than here, where wrong answers usually get corrected. The screenshots are very useful as proof of what this textbook actually says.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a wind instrument. The wind just makes the tubes bump against each other, or against the disk in the middle. The vibration frequency of a free metal cylinder or tube is not simply inverse proportional to length, because the restoring force is due to stiffness.

Approximate formulas for flexural resonances of free beams are given here: [hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/barres.html](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/barres.html)

Flexural modes of tubes have the same length dependence. The shortest one has the highest frequency.

Comment: But the answer in my textbook says that the rod with longest length will have highest pitch(frequency)

Comment: @Anubhav Rai, Your textbook is dead wrong.

Comment: @Digiproc I have seen this question at two places and both had answer number (1) i.e. c rod

Comment: One can already see from the question that the textbook is not that smart. Without knowing any physics or what the word frequency means, there are only two reasonable answers: the longest or the shortest tube. Then they managed to get confused. Then someone else copied. Get a refund!

Comment: @Pieter you can see that I have posted my textbook's answer after editing my question. The same question was also in another textbook with same answer. It can't be a coincidence that both gave wrong answer.

Comment: @AnubhavRai Yes, that is rather blatant. Not just a printing error. Anybody with ears can hear that they gave the wrong answer. Interesting!

Comment: @AnubhavRai If you still don't think the shortest rod gives the highest pitch, think about instruments like the xylophone, vibraphone, marimba, etc. The bars go from large to small in going from low to high pitch.